# Heroku App Succeed but NOT Succeed to Deploy

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I think I've succeeded to deploy my react app to Heroku according to this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bi1Z.jpg), but somehow when I open the app it just shows a "Not Found" text and an error message

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" on the console.

[image]

What does that means? What should I do?

Comment: Are you using React Router or other client-side router? Are you actually serving your app via a server?

Comment: yeah what's the issue?

Comment: okey that's a ton of parapraph, I think I'll go check it out tomorrow. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I recommend reading through it all if you really want to get to meat of the problem. The gist is that when you type a URL in the address bar, a request is made to the server at a certain route (server side). But React Router is completely client-side and done through JavaScript and the HTML5 History API. Thus, when the browser requests the route on your server, it doesn't exist as a route on the server, but a "pseudo-route" handled by JavaScript. The solution is you can redirect all requests to the server to your default HTML that includes the JavaScript that does your routing.